# Postgres - Sort by specific condition

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by

I have the following table.

table1

```
id      flag1           flag2           flag3           flag4
1       1               1               1               1               
2       1               1               1               0               
3       0               1               1               1               
4       1               0               1               1               
5       1               1               0               1               
6       0               1               1               0               
7       1               1               0               0               
8       0               0               1               1               
9       1               0               0               1               
10      0               0               0               1               
11      1               0               0               0               
12      0               1               0               0               
13      0               0               1               0
```

From the UI, I get a user-driven parameter called as `flag_priority`.

I have to sort the results based on the following condition:

- **PRIORITY 1** -- if flag1 = 1, flag2 = 1, flag3 = 1, flag4 = 1, then those records should be at the top
- **PRIORITY 2** -- if flag_priority == 'flag1', then order all the rows where flag1 = 1 and 2 out of 3 other flags are 1

  - (flag1 = 1, flag2 = 1, flag3 = 1, flag4 = 0) OR (flag1 = 1, flag2 = 0, flag3 = 1, flag4 = 1) OR (flag1 = 1, flag2 = 1, flag3 = 0, flag4 = 1)
- if flag_priority == 'flag4', then order all the rows where flag4 = 1 and 2 out of 3 other flags are 1

  - (flag1 = 0, flag2 = 1, flag3 = 1, flag4 = 1) OR (flag1 = 1, flag2 = 0, flag3 = 1, flag4 = 1) OR (flag1 = 1, flag2 = 1, flag3 = 0, flag4 = 1)
- **PRIORITY 3** -- if flag_priority == 'flag1', then order all the rows where flag1 = 1 and 1 out of 3 other flags are 1

  - (flag1 = 1, flag2 = 1, flag3 = 0, flag4 = 0) OR (flag1 = 1, flag2 = 0, flag3 = 1, flag4 = 0) OR (flag1 = 1, flag2 = 0, flag3 = 0, flag4 = 1)
- if flag_priority == 'flag4', then order all the rows where flag4 = 1 and 1 out of 3 other flags are 1

  - (flag1 = 1, flag2 = 0, flag3 = 0, flag4 = 1) OR (flag1 = 0, flag2 = 1, flag3 = 0, flag4 = 1) OR (flag1 = 0, flag2 = 0, flag3 = 1, flag4 = 1)
- **PRIORITY 4** -- if flag_priority == 'flag1', then order all the rows where flag1 = 1 and - out of 3 other flags are 1

  - (flag1 = 1, flag2 = 0, flag3 = 0, flag4 = 0)
- if flag_priority == 'flag4', then order all the rows where flag4 = 1 and 0 out of 3 other flags are 1

  - (flag1 = 1, flag2 = 0, flag3 = 0, flag4 = 0)

How to write the SQL query to order it based on the conditions above?

Answer (score 0):

I won't decipher all the conditions you have, but you can use a CASE expression in the ORDER BY. The idea is to convert each condition to a (single) number which indicates the sort position, something along the lines:

```
order by case
           when flag1 = 1 and flag2 = 1 and flag3 = 1 and flag4 = 1 then 1 
           when (flag1 = and flag2 = 1 and flag3 = 1 and flag4 = 0) 
                or (...) then 2
           when (flag1 = 1 and flag2 = 1 and flag3 = 0 and flag4 = 0)
                or (...) then 3
          end
```

If that is all part of a function, you can reference the function parameter in the CASE expressions as well, e.g.

```
when flag_parameter = 'flag1' 
     AND ((flag1 = 1 and flag2 = 1 and flag3 = 0 and flag4 = 0)
           or (...)) then ...
```

---

I wonder why you don't use a proper `boolean` for those flags (which would make the expressions a bit simpler as well e.g.: `when flag1 and flag2 and flag3 and flag4`